# Record count increases in PreSQL-Informatica in the absence of Semicolon (;), Database

Tags: teradata, informatica

My PreSQL query in the WorkFlow of Informatica has 2 parts:

1. Insert query
2. Refresh Stats procedure call

When no semicolon `;` is present between these 2 parts, the record count is given in Millions. When a semicolon ';' *is* present the record count is given in Thousands.

Two Questions:

1. Why is it not throwing an Error for the absence of a semicolon?
2. Why the increased record count?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

- Use a semicolon (;) to separate multiple statements. The Integration Service issues a commit after each statement.
- The Designer does not validate the SQL.

  It will not throw an error in power center because is not validating it. You can check logs on what SQL is getting passed to teradata and execute the same outside (any other client) to investigate on the row count diffference.

Comment: To check the record counts difference i tried to run the same query from the logs, It threw me an error! but in the Power center it is running perfectly and giving me unexpected record counts.